# Setting CreatedDate and LastModifiedDate in batch Apex

Tags: apex

We are writing batch Apex to convert Attachments to Files in our system. We chose the batch Apex approach for specific reasons.

Can we set the created date\last modified date through Apex on the Content Version object by reading it from the Attachment object?

I did read links in Google and it says we can set them through the API after we assign a system permission through a permission set.

Below is a small piece of relevant code that we have written in our batch Apex and this doesn't seem to work.

```
ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
cv.ContentLocation = 'S';                   
cv.Origin = 'C';
cv.VersionData = att.Body;
cv.OwnerId = att.OwnerId;
cv.createdById = att.OwnerId;
cv.Title = att.Name;
cv.PathOnClient = att.Name;
cv.CreatedDate = att.createdDate;
cv.LastModifiedDate = att.LastModifiedDate;
            
lstCV.add(cv);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to set any date audit fields in Apex (except in a test class).

The links you have read are referring to doing a data load via the API (e.g. using Apex Data Loader). That is currently the only way to set date audit fields to custom values.